# Python 2 and 3 compatible way of iterating through dict with key and value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-2.x

I have the following list comprehension that only works in Python 2 due to use of `iteritems()`:

```
foo = [key for key, value in some_dict.iteritems() if value['marked']]
```

I can't import any libraries. Is there a clean way of making this compatible on both Python 2 and 3?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can simply use `dict.items()` in both Python 2 and 3,

```
foo = [key for key, value in some_dict.items() if value['marked']]
```

Or you can simply roll your own version of `items` generator, like this

```
def get_items(dict_object):
    for key in dict_object:
        yield key, dict_object[key]
```

And then use it like this

```
for key, value in get_items({1: 2, 3: 4}):
    print key, value
```

Answer (score 12):

I would say is better to use `future` module than implementing your own, many stuff is already done for you in minimalistic/optimized way:

```
from future.utils import viewitems

foo = [key for key, value in viewitems(some_dict) if value.get('marked')]
```

if you are curious how this `viewitems()` is working, it's as simple as follows:

```
def viewitems(obj, **kwargs):
    """
    Function for iterating over dictionary items with the same set-like
    behaviour on Py2.7 as on Py3.

    Passes kwargs to method."""
    func = getattr(obj, "viewitems", None)
    if not func:
        func = obj.items
    return func(**kwargs)
```

**NB:**
if compatibility with Python versions before 2.7 is
    required then you should use `iteritems()`:

```
from future.utils import iteritems

foo = [key for key, value in iteritems(some_dict) if value.get('marked')]
```

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way is to not care about the list being created by just using `dict.items()`:

```
foo = [key for key, value in some_dict.items() if value['marked']]
```

The next option is to use an exception handler:

```
try:
    # Python 2
    iter_some_dict = some_dict.iteritems
except AttributeError:
    # Python 3
    iter_some_dict = some_dict.items

foo = [key for key, value in iter_some_dict if value['marked']]
```

What you use depends on how big `some_dict` gets and if the creation of the list for all items is going to have a sizeable impact on performance and your memory use. You'll have to benchmark your exact use-case to determine this.

Answer (score 3):

Define your own `iteritems`:

```
iteritems = lambda d: ((hasattr(d, 'iteritems') and d.iteritems) or d.items)()

foo = [key for key, value in iteritems(some_dict) if value['marked']]
```